# module 'torch.cuda' has no attribute 'memory_summary'

Tags: pytorch, gpu, torch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to measure the available space on each of my GPUs using `torch.cuda` module. However it is returning me the following error.

***module 'torch.cuda' has no attribute 'memory_summary'***

My code is below

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
        print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(i))
        a = torch.cuda.memory_summary(torch.device('cuda:{}'.format(i)))
        print(a)
```

Similarly `memory_stats`, `mem_get_info` and `memory_reserved` all are failing.

Comment: I tried your code in google colab and it works without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.cuda.memory_summary` is introduced in `Pytorch 1.4.0`. So if your torch install is older than that you won't be able to use it.